# Annotate feature in tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is `annotate` feature available somewhere in TortoiseHg 2.x?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Open up TortoiseHg Workbench on top of your repository.

Then click the Manifest button, it looks like this in the toolbar: [image: manifest button]

In the list, find the file you want to look at, right-click and choose *File History*:

[image: file history menu item]

In the dialog that opens up, in the toolbar just above the file contents, click the button for the annotation view:

[image: annotate button]

And then you should have your annotated view of the file. Note that a mouse-over on a line will show a status message at the very bottom of the window with the commit message and some details, but some details like single line changes with no content (ie. you added an empty line) might not give you a mouse-over. The revision number in the left column refers to an entry in the history list above the view though:

[image: annotate view]

Comment: Omg, it is so unobvious!! Thanks anyway. In thg 1.x it was much easier (and better).

Comment: I agree, but 2.0 is still young, give it time.

Comment: In version 2.1.3 the 'File history' menu entry is renamed to 'Annotate Files'.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You can follow the steps below.

- Launch TortoiseHg Workbench.
- Choose Repository -> Web Server... and run the server
- Browse to the repository
- Choose browse option
- Choose a specific file
- Click on annotate

Comment: Lol, to see annotate I need to start the webserver?! Why cannot I just type `hg annotate` instead? It is not tortoisehg solution, I can `serve` without it.